# how to make imagebutton in android stay highlighted?

Tags: java, android, button

if you click on a button in android, then it become orange, how would you make it stay like that in java? I tried setBackgroundcolor, but it change the shape of my button to the default shape when i use it and i dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not Possible for button as it does not have permanent focus but you can take one radio button and use **android:button="@drawable/yourselector"**. In Radio button you will get checked event and Radio Button checked is permanent state

Make a layout in res/draw able

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="false" 
             android:state_pressed="true"   
             android:drawable="@drawable/btn_attending_h" /> <!--clicked-->
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_attending"/> <!--not clicked-->
 </selector>
```